# sendgrid api java, do some APIs need to have sub-users, and sub-users need a paid version, right?

Tags: sendgrid

do some APIs need to have sub-users, and sub-users need a paid version, right? "sg.addRequestHeader("on-behalf-of", .." must the paid version be used if there is such a code in the program?

Comment: I've answered the question below, but perhaps you can explain what you are trying to do with this feature and I can maybe help in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

The [`on-behalf-of` SubUser header](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/how-to-use-the-sendgrid-v3-api/on-behalf-of-subuser) takes a SubUser username as an argument, so yes, it requires your account to have SubUsers and yes, you need to have a [Pro Email API or an Advanced Marketing Campaigns subscription](https://sendgrid.com/pricing/) to use SubUsers.

Comment: Note: The on-behalf-of header does not work with the mail.send API.
Why I can't use subuser account to send emails using mail.send api?

Comment: You should be able to use the `on-behalf-of` header with the mail send API. If you are having trouble with it I recommend you ask a new question and share your code and any errors that you are receiving.